# Bitmap in custom drawable matching parent below API 23

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have a `ListView` and its items have an arrow aligned to the end, like this:

[image]

The arrow is set in the background, which is a custom drawable:

**background_listitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:gravity="right|end|center_vertical"
        android:right="@dimen/preferred_margin">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

With **API > 22** this is working great but 22 and below the background looks like this:

[image]

This is how I am setting the background:

**listitem_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/listitem_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_listitem"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:padding="@dimen/preferred_margin">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any way to fix this **without** adding the arrow as an `ImageView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change you background_listitem.xml file like this i hope this is help you.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
            android:gravity="right|end|center_vertical" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, my brain was totally fried after couple of hours trying to solve this

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example but by making small change and it worked.
Instead of applying gravity to the `<item>` tag, I applied the tag to bitmap, and the result is clear to me.
My xml code is as follows:

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item >
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:gravity="center|right"/>
</item>
```

And in my layout I applied them to parent RelativeLayout as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Here are my results:
**Android API 23**
[image]

**Android API 19**
[image]

**Without gravity attribute in Android API 19**
[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for the answer! it is completely correct.. but the other guy was faster